Text fill effect but controlled by percentage
I'm attempting to create a text fill effect that will be controlled by a useState.
I have the following text:

According to a state I want it to be filled from left to right, although the last letter from the first text will be in a different color, for example:

The following code seems to work by half, but the fill is not syncronized and not with different colors:
'use client'

import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Intro = () => {
  const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0)

  // Function to dynamically create the gradient based on percentage
  const getGradient = (percentage) => {
    return `linear-gradient(to right, white ${percentage}%, transparent ${percentage}%)`
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-[100vh] flex items-center justify-center">
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <div>
          <span
            className="text-transparent italic text-[148px] text-stroke"
            style={{
              lineHeight: 0.8,
              backgroundImage: getGradient(percentage),
              WebkitBackgroundClip: 'text',
              backgroundClip: 'text',
            }}
          >
            PO
          </span>
          <span
            className="text-transparent italic pr-2 text-[148px] text-stroke"
            style={{
              lineHeight: 0.8,
              backgroundImage: getGradient(percentage),
              WebkitBackgroundClip: 'text',
              backgroundClip: 'text',
            }}
          >
            S
          </span>
        </div>
        <span
          className="text-transparent text-[30px] italic text-stroke-less"
          style={{
            lineHeight: 1,
            letterSpacing: 5.7,
            marginLeft: 6,
            backgroundImage: getGradient(percentage),
            WebkitBackgroundClip: 'text',
            backgroundClip: 'text',
          }}
        >
          PERFORMANCE
        </span>
      </div>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        value={percentage}
        onChange={(e) => setPercentage(e.target.value)}
        className="mt-4"
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Intro



I’m not quite understanding what “the fill is not synchronised” means. Could you explain a bit more what effect you want? With what is the fill to be synchronised?

@AHaworth What I tried to explain was, you can see that the PERFORMACE is being filled before the O from POS starts to get filled.
By synchronised, I'm trying to explain is, that the fill should be in the same position for both texts. So in the middle of the O from POS it should be more a less in the middle of performance too.
The animations should end at the same time.

I haven’t run the code, but rather than making the gradient to right try make it go at the same angle as the italicized text (probably about 120deg).

@Noleli That not the main issue, the issue is the filling

Each part has its own background. Percentage of what?

@AHaworth according to the percentage, it will fill the hole area. So for example, 50%, would fill, P and O (until half) and performance until (perfor, half of the R)

I think it would help understanding if you could create a runnable snippet. Use <> in the editor and check it shows the problem.

From the information provided in your comment, it seems that you want to make POS synchronize with PERFORMANCE for a left-to-right gradient animation. If so, try this:
<div class="flex h-dvh flex-col items-center justify-center bg-black">
  <article class="relative">
    <!-- text stroke -->
    <section class="absolute inset-0 flex flex-col items-center px-10 text-transparent">
      <div class="text-[148px] italic"><span style="-webkit-text-stroke: 1px white">PO</span><span style="-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #3b82f6">S</span></div>
      <span class="text-[40px] italic" style="-webkit-text-stroke: 1px white">PERFORMANCE</span>
    </section>
    <!-- current fill pivot: 50%; 10% gradient effect -->
    <section class="flex flex-col items-center px-10 text-white" style="mask:linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, transparent calc( 50% + 10% ));">
      <div class="text-[148px] italic">PO<span class="text-blue-500">S</span></div>
      <span class="text-[40px] italic">PERFORMANCE</span>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>

Static DEMO on Tailwind Play.
You can achieve the animation effect by dynamically modifying the percentage:
<div
  className="flex flex-col items-center px-10 text-white"
  style={{
    mask: `linear-gradient(to right, black ${percentage}%, transparent calc( ${percentage}% + 10% ))`,
  }}
>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>


This seems to have lost the initial text outline.

@AHaworth I'm sorry. I didn't notice that requirement earlier. I've updated the answer to include text stroke.

This is exactly what I needed, I made something too and will send here
